# Trying to figure out code snippet in the book Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Chapter 3 Functions has the following code snippet:

```
const power = function(base, exponent) {
let result = 1;
for(let count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
result *= base;
}
return result;
}; 
console.log(power(2, 10));
// 1024
```

can someone explain what is going on in the code line by line, i'm confused by let result = 1 the most. Thanks!

Comment: See the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). Try to go through this code yourself first, step by step.

Comment: Assuming that exponent will be `>= 0`, `1` is the base result that will be used when calling for example `power(2, 0)`. Note the loop won't execute on this case, and 1 will be returned (since `2^0 = 1`). On the other side, the loop just multiplies the `base` by itself `exponent` number of times.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line, you're declaring a variable `result`. However, it's being declared with `let`, not `var`. Let is similar to var, except it can't be accessed outside the block it is defined in (including functions, loops and conditional statements). And since it's in a function here, that first line is equivalent to:

```
var result = 1;
```

---

In the second line:

```
for (let count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {}
```

You're looping over `exponent` - so the code within the `{}` of the loop will be executed `exponent` times.

---

In the third line:

```
result *= base;
```

You're multiplying `result` and `base`, and assigning the value to `result`. This line is equivalent to:

```
result = result * base;
```

---

Final line:

```
return result;
```

This line stops the function and returns `result`. The return means that whenever a function is called, it essentially is replaced with the return value (like in this line):

```
console.log(power(2, 10));
```

This calls `power()` with arguments 2 and 10, and logs the returned value to the console.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. As a novice to JS, it's nice to not be judged on your level of experience and privilege so, thank you!

Comment: No problem whatsoever @Jay, I'm always glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

This example is a simple approach of building and executing an exponential function in JavaScript.

That said, we know that the below will essentially be creating something like the following in pseudocode: 
`print the result of (number to the power of some other number)`

The code walkthrough:

```
// initialize a constant variable named 'power' as a function declaration with two arguments, 'base' and 'exponent' which will be used inside the function
const power = function(base, exponent) {
// declare and initialize variable called 'result' and set it with value of 1
// why this is 1, is because any number to the power of 1 is itself, so rather than setting this to 0, this must be 1 to ensure that the exponential function works accurately
let result = 1;
// let count = 0; this will initialize a variable named count to be used within the loop
// count < exponent; this is the conditional statement, it means that the loop will continue looping until the condition is met, meaning loop until 'count' is no longer less than 'exponent'
// count++; this increments the value of the initial variable, in this case 'count' for every trip through the loop for the duration that the condition statement remains true  
for (let count = 0; count < exponent; count++) {
// multiply the 'result' variable by the 'base' variable and set it as the new value of the 'result' variable
result *= base;
}
// return the 'result' variable so that it is now available outside of the function
return result;
}; 
// pass in the 'base' and 'exponent' arguments for the function 'power' in order to get the value (effectively, 2^10), and then print this value to the console
console.log(power(2, 10));
// 1024
```